# Convert 4 lines of Jquery to Mootools

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

The following lines of code do two things. The first two lines add classes to the siblings immediately before and after an element with a given id (in this case a UL with id "nav")

The last two lines add the classes first and last to the first and last sibling elements whose parent has the id "nav".

This is jquery. How would I achieve the same with Mootools 1.11. Any help appreciated.

```
$('#nav .active').prev().addClass('prevtab');
$('#nav .active').next().addClass('nexttab');
$('#nav').children(":first").addClass('first');
$('#nav').children(":last").addClass('last');
```

---

formatting doesn't work in comments so repeating for zombat:

Using mootools 1.1
There is no edit button available to me, and I can't comment as I don't have enough rep.

Your solution is doing something, but not targeting the correct element.

This is the result I want and am getting with jquery:

```
<ul id="nav">
<li class="first"></li>
<li></li>
<li class="prevtab"></li>
<li class="active"></li>
<li class="nexttab"></li>
<li class="last"></li>
</ul>
```

This is the result of your js:

```
<div class="prevtab"></div>
<ul id="nav">
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li class="active"></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
<div class="nexttab"><div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Give this a shot.

```
$('nav').getNext().addClass('nexttab');
$('nav').getPrevious().addClass('prevtab');
var c = $('nav').getChildren();
c[0].addClass('first');
c[c.length-1].addClass('last');
```

Edit: Working now.

Second/Third edits:

Ok, I misunderstood the way you're using the .active class.  Try this:

```
var n = $('nav').getElement('.active').getNext();
if (n) n.addClass('nexttab');
var p = $('nav').getElement('.active').getPrevious();
if (p) p.addClass('prevtab');
var c = $('nav').getChildren();
c[0].addClass('first');
c[c.length-1].addClass('last');
```

Comment: Very close now, thank you zombat.
Within the ul#nav element, everything works perfectly when elements other then the first and last li are active.

If the first or last li's are active, the none of the classes(nexttab,prevtab, first,last) are added at all.

strange :)

Comment: Ah, yeah, there was a JS error if there was no prev/next element, so the whole script would stop.  I gave it another edit, see how that goes.  Sorry for the weak JS-fu.

Answer (score 0):

```
$each($$('#nav .active'),function(item){
                            item.getPrevious().classname='prevtab';
                         }
      );
```

This is the first line.

Second you can use getNext
Third you can use $('#nav').getFirst //make sure it has children....
Fourth  you can use getLast